# How to compare two elements without ids or classes jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having a problem with matching elements in jQuery.
Basically I have list items, and `onclick` I want to compare two elements to find out its position within the list, ie.

```
<ul id="someID">
    <li>something</li>
    <li>something</li>
    <li>something</li>
</ul>

// here is the script
var row = 0,
    element = $('#someID > li:eq(1)').get(0);

$('#someID > li').each(function(index, value) {
    if (value == element) {
        row = index;
        return false;
    }
}
```

`element` is in the proper scope and this all should work (or so I think). The only reason I can see that it might not work is that the browser sees each `list-item` as the same, because its `innerHTML` is the same and has no `id` or `class`.

Is there some other way that I can get the position of a list-item within a list?

Comment: Your code works for me as long as you add the closing parenthesis that you're missing. Try it: http://jsfiddle.net/83hcP/

Comment: Well its a good thing I found out about index(), that nice. But it turns out that that wasn't actually my problem, it was the #someID. This was my code simplified, and I was not getting the correct element to loop through.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var index = $('#someID > li').index( element );
```

[index](http://api.jquery.com/index/)

Answer (score 1):

To compare elements try:

```
value === element
```

== is coersive comparison.

=== is explicit comparison.

To get position of an element with jQuery, read awnsers from the other people ;)

Answer (score 1):

For the record, now there is the "is()" function:

```
element.is(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason $.index() does not work for you...

Any reason you can't add an attribute or class to the object then loop through the list of items to find it?

```
$('li').click(function() 
{
  $(this).addClass('Selected');
  .. loop through element to find index
     .HasClass('Selected');      

  $(this).removeClass('Selected');
})
```